# c# Azure Mobile Apps - Adding new model not working

Tags: c#, azure, mobile, azure-mobile-services

I created an Azure Mobile App , then downloaded the generated backend and mobile app . When i start it , it successfully gets the 2 todo items in the db. However as soon as i add the user model as below - it stops getting the todo items in the mobile app . I have no idea what is causing a conflict.

- If i remove the user model & references , i can once again retrieve the todo items on the mobile app

When i comment out this line from the DBcontext , it works again :

```
//public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
```

Startup :

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public static void ConfigureMobileApp(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            //For more information on Web API tracing, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=620686 
            config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();

            new MobileAppConfiguration()
                .UseDefaultConfiguration()
                .ApplyTo(config);

            // Map routes by attribute
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            // Use Entity Framework Code First to create database tables based on your DbContext
            Database.SetInitializer(new AuthApp231Initializer());

            // To prevent Entity Framework from modifying your database schema, use a null database initializer
            // Database.SetInitializer<AuthApp231Context>(null);

            MobileAppSettingsDictionary settings = config.GetMobileAppSettingsProvider().GetMobileAppSettings();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.HostName))
            {
                // This middleware is intended to be used locally for debugging. By default, HostName will
                // only have a value when running in an App Service application.
                app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
                    ValidAudiences = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"] },
                    ValidIssuers = new[] { ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"] },
                    TokenHandler = config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
                });
            }
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }

    public class AuthApp231Initializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<AuthApp231Context>
    {
        protected override void Seed(AuthApp231Context context)
        {
            List<TodoItem> todoItems = new List<TodoItem>
            {
                new TodoItem { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "First item", Complete = false },
                new TodoItem { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Text = "Second item", Complete = false },
            };

            foreach (TodoItem todoItem in todoItems)
            {
                context.Set<TodoItem>().Add(todoItem);
            }

            /*List<User> users = new List<User>
            {
                new User { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Username = "adrian", Password = "supersecret" }
            };

            foreach (User user in users)
            {
                context.Set<User>().Add(user);
            }*/

            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

DataObjects :

```
public class User :EntityData
    {

        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Context :

```
public class AuthApp231Context : DbContext
    {
        // You can add custom code to this file. Changes will not be overwritten.
        // 
        // If you want Entity Framework to alter your database
        // automatically whenever you change your model schema, please use data migrations.
        // For more information refer to the documentation:
        // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

        private const string connectionStringName = "Name=MS_TableConnectionString";

        public AuthApp231Context() : base(connectionStringName)
        {
        } 

        public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Add(
                new AttributeToColumnAnnotationConvention<TableColumnAttribute, string>(
                    "ServiceTableColumn", (property, attributes) => attributes.Single().ColumnType.ToString()));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I known, the sample mobile app back-end project only contains the `TodoItem` model, when you run your project, the `Database.SetInitializer(new AuthApp231Initializer())` would be triggered and create the database and `TodoItem` table when the database does not exist. If you add another data models after the database is initialized, you need to migrate your database.

**Note:** You could leverage `Add-Migration` to add customizing migrations and use `Update-Database` to bring your database up-to-date. Also, you could leverage the `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion` Initializer to automatically upgrade your database.

For more details about how to enable EF Code First Migrations, you could refer to this official [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To add a model to an existing project, you need to do the following:

1. Add the Data Transfer Object
2. Add the DbSet to the context
3. Add a TableController for the new DTO
4. Set up and execute a migration against the target database, or otherwise create the appropriate table in the database

You've described that you have done #1 and #2.  You have made no indication that you have done #3 or #4.

For more information, check out my book at http://aka.ms/zumobook - especially chapter 3.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I actually followed your book (Chapter 2) to implement the authentication . I followed all the steps but couldn't get it to work . Also for the user model . DataAnnotations is no longer valid , that's why i used EntityData for the user .

Comment: EntityData is just an implementation of ITableData, which uses Entity Framework.  The DataAnnotations comes from Entity Framework.  If you have upgraded to the .NETCore edition of Entity Framework (which you most definitely should not do), then this is the likely outcome.